# Не работает модуль "star_rating" на Evolution2.0, MySql5.7, PHP7.2. General error: 2014 by setting the PDO::MYSQL_ATTR_USE_BUFFERED_QUERY attribute

Tags: php, mysql, modx, evolution, star-rating

При попытке установки получил ошибку:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Решил установить вручную: добавил таблицы с setup.sql, в результате сам модуль просто сжирает память, на этапе коннекта, при этом записи с фронта добавляются в базу.
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]
Могу дать доступ для теста. Заранее благодарю за помощь.

Comment: Вы кажется ошиблись вам нужно на фриланс биржу) А так вообще не понятно, что за модуль, какие у вас там данные в бд, разбирались ли вы в своём модуле или хотите чтоб за вас кто-то разобрался, а вам потом сказал что не так было, если есть конкретные вопросы пожалуйста задавайте, но уж точно никто не будет решать за вас ваши же проблемы.

Comment: Название модуля в заголовке, видно что вы с modx не работали, зачем тогда отвечать)

Comment: затригерило "Могу дать доступ для теста.", название модуля в заголовке мне не о чём не говорит как и всем остальным